# Global Array in laravel controller

Tags: php, laravel

I have defined array as a global.In one function I am adding values to it and in another function I am trying to displaying it.Everytime I get NO ERROR but while I am getting ) value. Whereas It shows values in the function 1 after adding value but not in function 2;

```
class ExamController extends Controller
  {
  public $question_array=[];
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->question_array=[];
    }
    public function start_exam(Request $request,$id_exam)
    {
     $question=DB::table('exam_question')->where('id_exam',$id_exam)->get();
     foreach($question as $q)
      {
        $this->question_array= explode(',',$q->id_question);
      } 
    }
  public function test(Request $request){  
         print_r($this->question_array);  
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to append results from `explode()`? Then, you must use `array_merge(original_value, explode(...))`, otherwise, the array will be rewritten on every loop iteration.

Comment: i dont wan to append it,I have question ids in string format in DB like 12,34,10,15

Comment: I am making array of it and trying to put in $this->question_array

Comment: You have to understand request/response cycle. On request started in `test` method (i.e. clicking link that points to action in `ExamController::test`) `$this->question_array` will be empty. Every new request (e.g. click to link) object is being instantiated and property will be initially empty.